# Ignore prevent default with an onclick function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a custom "view cart" link to a Woocommerce message after adding a product to the cart. The link shows the correct URL but does nothing when it's clicked. Considering the circumstances I'm going to assume this is due to a prevent.default method but I don't know for sure.

The link is inside a php string and calls a variable which holds the correct cart URL:

```
sprintf( __('Products successfully added to cart! <a href="%s" onclick="cartLink()" title="cart" class="notification-cart-link">View cart</a>','sf-theme'),$cartURL );
```

Which comes out like this:

```
<p id="addToCartMessage"><span class="text-success">Products successfully added to cart! <a href="http://webshop.local/cart/" onclick="cartLink()" title="cart" class="notification-cart-link" id="view-cart">View cart</a></span></p>
```

I did find a workaround by simply creating a jQuery function with the link to the cart page then adding this as onclick in the HTML but for this I have to enter the exact URL in the function which could cause problems if the link ever changes.

```
// Add to cart link
function cartLink() {
    var url = 'http://webshop.local/cart/';
    window.location = url;
}
```

Is there a way to ignore or bypass a prevent.default method with an onclick function?

Comment: `preventDefault()` not an event, but a method available in an event handler function.

Comment: @connexo ah alright my mistake, still learning, I'll edit the question ;-)

Comment: Please show the element's HTML exactly as it arrives in your browser.

Comment: Added the HTML exactly as it shows up in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the URL from the link being clicked (the element which triggers the event is available as `e.target` in your listener):

```js
var link = document.getElementById('view-cart');

// let's assume some Javascript has added a listener which does preventDefault()
// so now clicking it does nothing (the following 3 lines simulate that)
link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
})

// now let's console.log the href of the link on click
link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.href);
  // you wanna do this here:
  // window.location.href = e.target.href
})
```

```html
<p id="addToCartMessage"><span class="text-success">Products successfully added to cart! <a href="http://webshop.local/cart/" title="cart" class="notification-cart-link" id="view-cart">View cart</a></span></p>
```

If anything remains unclear, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for but I'm having trouble getting this to work in my code. I copied your answer and made some necessary changes. Keep getting reference errors for the ID's. Do I need to add a separate button for this to work or could I just stick with the one link?

Comment: Adjusted the example to the HTML you added to your question. I'm still unsure as of what's going on on your side. I understood you have a fully working `a` tag on which some JS does `preventDefault()` when clicked. That means the full `href` is already there and all you want to achieve is that clicking the link has the normal behaviour of opening the `href`?

Comment: Thank you and yes that is correct. I can see no issues with the `a` tag. When hovered it shows the correct link and when this link is clicked in the Chrome inspector the page opens. No errors are present in the console either. It's just when I click the link nothing happens which is why I suspected a `preventDefault()`. I hoped to disable this "rogue" `preventDefault()` or whatever was preventing this specific link of acting like it should.

Comment: Well, I gave you everything you need to "restore" the natural behaviour of the link.

Comment: Yes you did and now I got it working so thank you I really appreciate your help!